# how to configure database for errai project using hibernate

Tags: hibernate, errai

Hi I am creating errai web services.I have to configure Database for this project but tried errai kitchensink but database configuration is not working.Plz suggest solution.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm really curious why you want to involve `Errai` with the database (via `Hibernate`) this much, `Errai` is a **client/server bus**, you use it to transport data-back and forth, the db access should be done separately on the server side usually. You need to create a `DAO` for that which will be called by your server side `Errai` service implementation.